# Por qué TailwindCSS no me muestras los estilos en mi HTML?

Tags: html, css, tailwind

Estoy haciendo una página para aprender y practicar Tailwind, pero al colocar las clases en mis etiquetas html, no se cambian los estilos.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practicando Tailwindcss</title>
    <link href="/public/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="bg-black text-white">
        <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold">titulo</h1>
        <ul class="flex">
            <li>inicio</li>
            <li>nsdfsf</li>
            <li>sdf</li>
            <li>contacto</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```

Ese es el código que llevo, soy nueva con este framework asique nose cual puede llegar a ser el problema ni tampoco se que información hay que dar para que resuelvan este problema, asique si necesitan mas información díganme, desde ya agradezco el tiempo de respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

He consultado la [documentación de Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn). Tiene varias maneras de instalación y una de ellas es insertando un script en tu documento HTML.

```js
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Prueba a ejecutar este ejemplo, donde inserto ese script y muestro el mismo `body` que aparece en tu documento. Faltaría incluir los estilos de tu archivo output.css, pero no importa.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header class="bg-black text-white">
    <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold">titulo</h1>
    <ul class="flex">
        <li>inicio</li>
        <li>nsdfsf</li>
        <li>sdf</li>
        <li>contacto</li>
    </ul>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas graciass @Smashoverflow, sabia sobre este script, no sabia que era necesario, creí que solo se utilizaba cuando estabas en un playground. Gracias tu agradezco tu tiempo!!

Comment: Por favor, marca esta respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió. Gracias.